# Create a symlink in iCloud Drive to another Directory in iCloud Drive

Tags: icloud, finder

I want to create a link to a folder in iCloud Drive from another location in iCloud Drive, I want the link to work on MacOS & iOS. I can't figure out a solution so far.

Things I've tried so far:

**Symlink strategy**

`ln -s ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/source_dir ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/dest_link`

**Alias Strategy**

1. Right-click on source directory > **Make Alias** option in the menu

**Smart Folder Strategy**

1. **File** > **New Smart Folder**
2. Add a new row for search criteria
3. Set **Document Container** equal to "source_dir"

**Results**

| Strategy | Works on MacOS? | Works on iOS? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Symlink | ✅ YES | ❌ NO |
| Alias | ✅ YES | ❌ NO |
| Smart Folder | ❌ NO | ❌ NO |

**Summary**

How can I create a link to another folder in iCloud that works on both macOS and iOS?

Comment: The question has come up before, but I haven't found the older one. iOS supports neither smart folders nor user-level symlinks.

Comment: Neither does the web version of iCloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this as it's not implemented for cloud and iOS.

Sadly, suggesting a feature or feedback to Apple is the only thing I could see getting it prorated. Or choose another storage ecosystem. OneDrive has some features like this at some price points and configurations.